# MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter.Can't get working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, binding

I'm currently trying to get working a code the major point of which is a  binding of three incoming vars with the User Control. The last one, as it's planned, should swap its colour depending on logic implemented in IMultiValueConverter.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TestApp_WPF.User_Controls.Axis"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:TestApp_WPF.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp_WPF.User_Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="UserControl_Axis"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Converters:WyeDeltaMultiConverter x:Key="WDMultiConverter" />

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse
            Width="17"
            Height="17"
            Stroke="Black">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WDMultiConverter}">

                    <Binding Path="Prty_L_feedback" />

                    <Binding Path="Prty_D_feedback" />

                    <Binding Path="Prty_Axis_failed" />

                </MultiBinding
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**WDMultiConverter:**

```
class WyeDeltaMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter

{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? state_0 = values[0] as bool?;
        bool? state_1 = values[1] as bool?;
        bool? state_2 = values[2] as bool?;

        if (state_0 == null && state_1 == null && state_2 == null)
            return Brushes.OrangeRed;

        if (state_0 == true && state_1 == null && state_2 == null)
            return Brushes.Azure;

        if (state_0 == true && state_1 == true && state_2 == null)
            return Brushes.LawnGreen;

        if (state_0 == true && state_1 == true && state_2 == null)
            return Brushes.OrangeRed;

        return Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```

Any suggestions please!

Comment: "swap its colour"? Your converter takes three bool values and returns a brush. What brush do you expect it to return and what does it actually return when you run the application? Brushes.OrangeRed will never be returned because you are returning Brushes.LawnGreen for the same condition.

Comment: The code in Converter is just a sketch. I'm interested in the another stuff. How to bind  Multibinding  properly.

Comment: I suggest you put a break point in and see what you actually get.

Comment: Just a sketch? So what are you trying to to? What brush does your converter return? It's this one that you'll see in the Ellipse.

Comment: I'm interested in the another stuff. How to bind Multibinding properly? I think if I do MultiBinding properly I will able to solve all logical issues.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You already bind to multiple properties. The converter is supposed to return a brush based on the values of all source properties you bind to.

Comment: Could anyone guide me how to do MultiBinding properly in that case?

Comment: Why do you think it is not properly bound? Can you share test cases (values of the bound properties, expected brush, observed brush)?

Comment: @mm8, first please consider that Converter's and XAML code maybe totally wrong despite the lack of syntax fails.

Comment: Above all I'm interested in by which way Converter recognizes which incoming vars belongs to value[0], value[1], value[2]. I failed to trace that in the code.

Comment: It takes bindings in the order in which you specify them in xaml. Your code looks fine by the way.

Comment: @Dmitry, so that means Path="Prty_L_feedback" corresponds value[0],  Path="Prty_D_feedback" corresponds value[1] and Path="Prty_Axis_failed" corresponds value[2]???

Comment: Yes in this case that's the values you should get

Comment: @mm8 wrote: 'Brushes.OrangeRed will never be returned because you are returning Brushes.LawnGreen for the same condition.' Btw, that's the case. It returns always Brushes.OrangeRed!

Comment: @Dmitry, much appreciate. You told me an useful theory stuff.)

Comment: @Redneck: I was looking at the second last return statement. This will never be hit.  Apparently you have another one that also returns Brushes.OrangeRed.

Answer (score 0):

Rumours about uselfulness of this resource are clearly overblown. Today's example just prooved that. There have been here a few guys which lost their interest quite quickly. Perhaps in the past, I'm judging by long-standing posts, this resource were visited by real guru of the code. Unfortunately not these days.
Also it's worth noting that resource has quite unfriendly interface and scoring system.

An answer that was founded by myself: it was missing *ElementName* in each Binding.

```
<Binding ElementName="UserControl_Axis" Path="Prty_L_feedback" />

<Binding ElementName="UserControl_Axis" Path="Prty_D_feedback" />

<Binding ElementName="UserControl_Axis" Path="Prty_Axis_failed" />
```

Of course after getting XAML code working properly I made some changes in so-called Boolean Logic which is located in the Converter.

That's all.